# Character Panel is stuck off screen after unplugging an external monitor; how to bring it back to my screen?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Take a look at the following screenshot

[image]

The Character panel is stuck off screen on Illustrator on my Mac. This often happens when I unplug my external monitor. I then sit down to work the character pane (command-T) always appears half-offscreen, and I cannot find  way to bring it back to my screen.

The only way that I found to get my Character panel back is to find an external screen and plug it in, then move my character panel back on to my laptop screen, then re-unplug the external screen.

Is there any other way to "factory reset" the location of the Character pane?

Answer (score 2):

Choose a workspace from `Window > Workspace >`

That will reset panels to the saved location in the selected workspace.